# EF Reverse POCO against a SQL Database Project?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, database-project

**Can I use the EF Reverse POCO generator directly against a SQL Database Project?**

I keep my SQL database definition in a "Visual Studio SQL Database Project", which gives me some nice version control capabilities, schema comparison, and a few nifty deployment features. Sometimes I update the project files from a temporary database during development, but the version-controlled project is always the "truth" for any version.

If I use the [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator](http://efreversepoco.codeplex.com/), will I need to round-trip my "truth" through an actual SQL database to generate POCO? Or can I use the POCO generator against a VS Database Project?

I know that the schema of a database project has a sort of meta-presence in various VS database interactions. For example, it shows up with a real database icon in the SQL Server Object Explorer. But I don't know if the code-first generator could/does leverage a similar ability to query it for metadata.

Comment: Currently (VS 2013) this is not possible. BTW this question was asked at the following link, though there aren't any helpful answers yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392636/generate-entity-framework-model-from-visual-studio-database-project

Comment: Thank you Keith. Of course the question you mentioned isn't directly related to the tool I was hoping to use, which gets pretty close to the solution already. I don't think that tool was even mentioned in the thread, unless it's part of the EF Power Tools (and I don't think it is). So I wonder, do you know specifically that the reverse POCO generator doesn't have that ability?

Comment: Correct, it currently does not have that ability. It would be a great feature to have though!

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [SqlSharpener](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener) on GitHub available as a NuGet package.

Description:

> Parses SQL files to create a meta-object hierarchy with which you can
>   generate C# code such as stored procedure wrappers or Entity Framework
>   Code-First entities. Generate either manually or by invoking one of
>   the included pre-compiled T4 templates.
>
> Rather than generating code from the database or using a heavy
>   abstraction layer that might miss differences between the database and
>   data access layer until run-time, this project aims to provide a very
>   fast and simple data access layer that is generated at design-time
>   using SQL files as the source-of-truth (such as those found in an SSDT
>   project).

I cannot vouch for it because I have never used it but it seems promising.

Comment: Awesome find, thank you Keith. I will investigate it over the next couple days and reply here.

Comment: I should also mention that I get the impression from Rowan Miller after some public discussion that MS is considering adding this feature to VS 2015.

Comment: @shannon, I'm the creator of SqlSharpener. You should definitely be able to do what you are asking using it. I have added a [T4 template](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener/blob/master/examples/SimpleExample/SimpleExample.DataLayer/EFCodeFirstExample.tt) in the [example solution](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener/tree/master/examples/SimpleExample) that you can use to generate your entities. If there is a use-case that isn't covered, feel free to [create an issue](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener/issues) and I'll see if I can account for it.

Answer (score 0):

For [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838), you would need to round-trip through an actual SQL database to generate the code-first code as you cannot use generator against a VS Database Project.