# How to generate EF model with tables created with SSDT in project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on a project and I had to add a SQL Database project to the project, so I created the tables with SSDT and I was asked to implement EF6 to the project and I was wondering how to generate the EF Model from the SQL database project?

Comment: Can't you just create your model from the database itself (as opposed to the database project)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Reverse POCO against a SQL Database Project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179726/ef-reverse-poco-against-a-sql-database-project/30240409#30240409)

Comment: @Pawel, I can't because the database is a SQL database project. If it was based off of a normal SQL database then it would be easier and no problem. It was my first time adding a SQL database project using ssdt. Normally I don't use ssdt and just use SSMS and do things thatvway

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that I needed to publish the SQL Database Project, once I did that I was able to generate the EF classes.